# CSS works fine on Local host but when I access from server no styling

Tags: html, css

The CSS folder is up one from html and thought I solved it with CSS/styles

```
<link rel="stylesheet"
href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l"
crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
```

should be

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/styles.css">
```

Comment: Thanks Boris. Tried that, but no luck so far. Wondering now if a larger issue on html since the deployed site also not rendering a navbar.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the input. The issue was not on html side but on js. Am using express and the last line of code fixed the styling issue.

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const https = require("https");

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.static("public"));
```